# DELL Studio 14 Battery LED flashing

Tags: battery, led, dell-studio, flashing

My laptop DELL Studio 14's Battery LED suddenly flashes in orange-orange-orange-white-blank sequence. Anybody tried before?

Exact model number is DELL Studio 1435.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means the battery is over heated, let it cool down for several hours. See this document, its near the bottom under "Charging the battery"

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/xlob/dtg/en/power.htm#wp1211233

You can Run the Dell hardware diagnostics, When you power up the laptop hit F12 repeatedly when you see the Dell logo splash screen, then select Diagnostics. run the extended tests. I would wait for the battery to cool off before you do this.

.

All your Dell docs for that model
.

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/1435/en/index.htm

.

Main page for that model
.

http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/dsn/en/entry?

.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my battery is not overheat (because the room temperature is 4 degree Celsius). Maybe the sensor is failed.

Comment: Take the battery out and pop it in the freezer for 20 minutes, put it back in, see if you get the same blink code.